# wp7 unicode characters display as square

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

i want to add some emotions to my twitter client app, such as: ಥ_ಥ (,,Ծ‸Ծ,,)
and some one has special character in his user name,
but the characters don't show up, just displayed as 口口. 
here is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button
            Content="(,,&#x053E;&#x2038;&#x053E;,,)
            (,,Ծ‸Ծ,,)
            &#x221a;
            ಠ_ಠ
            ✧ (≖ ‿ ≖)✧"
            />            
    </Grid>
```

otherwise, they displayed well on SMS and Internet Explorer,

screenshot is here: http://sdrv.ms/171Qf7t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have changed your default font somewhere to one that doesn't have those Unicode characters. Either return to the default font or use something like:

```
<Button
  Content="(,,&#x053E;&#x2038;&#x053E;,,)
           ಠ_ಠ
           ✧ (≖ ‿ ≖)✧" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold"
        />
```

which displays correctly when I test it here.

Comment: i've tried your code, but it doesn't work. it seems that the font doesn't contain some Unicode chars.So i have to embed my own font. Anyway, thanks a lot for reply